# theme: Szeged - how to edit header

Tags: beamer, themes, rmarkdown

I am using RMarkdown Beamer and I set the theme: Szeged in the YAML header as per:

```
---
title: title

author: name
date: date

output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: Szeged
    slide_level: 2
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
      
linkcolor: blue
---
```

`header.tex`

```
% remove title slides at beginning of sections
\AtBeginSection{}
% add page counter to the footer
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
```

But I would like to remove the second section (between the 2nd and 3rd line) since I do not have anything there:

[image]

How can I do it?

Is it possible to change the colour of these lines as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following to the TeX file:

```
% remove 2nd section from header
\makeatletter
\beamer@theme@subsectionfalse
\makeatother
% change colour of lines
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{7,75,164}
\setbeamercolor{separation line}{bg=mycolor}
```